# Calling CreateScope() or BeginScope() Manually inside azure function

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am writing an eventhub triggered azure function that receives a list of objects in each event from eventhub. I want to instantiate an object of some type for each object of the list that I receive. If I register that type as scoped by calling builder.Services.AddScoped I will have new instance for each eventhub event(for each function call). I want to control the instance creation. SO I want to have something like bellow inside my function.

```
 using (var scope = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
            {
               // scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(type)
            }
```

In that way for each object in the list inside each event hub event I can have new Instance of some type.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I call .CreateScope() inside azure function instead of letting .net call it.

Comment: Inject `IServiceProvider` into your function. Though you could probably just make the service transient and avoid creating a scope.

Comment: @DavidG IServiceProvider does not expose CreateScope() methoed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution of my problem. Inside Configure method of Startup we can register `ServiceProvider` like bellow

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEventContext, EventContext>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceProvider>(builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider());
```

Then we can set `ServiceProvider` as a dependency in the function app class and we can call `CreateScope()` directly like bellow inside function

```
 using (var scope = this._serviceProvider.CreateScope())
      {
          var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IEventContext>();

          var ctx2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IEventContext>();

          this._logger.LogInformation(ctx.GetHashCode().ToString());  //same
          this._logger.LogInformation(ctx2.GetHashCode().ToString());  //same
               
       }
```